# How to extends Sequelize 4 Model in ES6 classes?

Tags: node.js, sequelize.js

**I want to make a class which extends Sequelize Model like below**

```
const Sequelize = require('sequelize');

class MyModel extends Sequelize.Model {
   constructor(){
     super()
   }

}
```

But I need to know how to define/init table name and attributes for this MyModel.**I want every method of Sequelize.Model into MyModel**

Comment: I just wrote an article how we achieved this: https://medium.com/@ismayilkhayredinov/sequelize-model-loading-with-es6-ffe4f38fd9b6

Answer (score 6):

You can do it like this

To Define Models =>

```
const Sequelize = require("sequelize");
class MyModel extends Sequelize.Model {
  static init(sequelize, DataTypes) {
    return super.init(
      {
        myField: DataTypes.STRING
      },
      { sequelize }
    );
  }
}
```

and to define associations

```
const Sequelize = require("sequelize");
class MyModel extends Sequelize.Model {
  static associate(models) {
    this.myAssociation = this.belongsTo(models.OtherModel);
    // or
    this.myAssociation = models.MyModel.belongsTo(models.OtherModel);
  }
}
```

You can use it like this for more details follow from [this](https://codewithhugo.com/using-es6-classes-for-sequelize-4-models/) blog. I have used it from here

Comment: just wondering, what is exactly is the this.myAssociation in your association. Where did it come from? Thanks.

Comment: it can be any name you want to access your associated models